# Recreate an Azure VM from a disk image

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, cloud

Someone managed to delete (instead of deallocate) a VM from our portal.azure.com account. It's apparently quite a quick and unceremonious process.

The `.vhd` still exists and I have a rough idea of the grade of VM it was. It seems that 99% of the instructions out there make it look very easy but are for the old manage.windowsazure.com site, which does not seem to apply. This is not a classic VM and it's storage is not even visible in the old manager.

I have both the cross platform command line tools and the azure cmdlets for powershell installed, but do not know what command to use, let alone what parameters to set.

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/201-vm-from-specialized-vhd/

Since you know that the disk exists, you should be able to supply values for the OS disk parameters required by the above process.